# Edit url of an online video in powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

Is it possible to edit the url of an already embedded online video in powerpoint? Or do I have to insert a new online video when the url of the video changes? Appreciate your help

Comment: You can determine the URL with this: MsgBox activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName   
And possibly change it with this:
activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = "newURL"

Comment: Where do I put this code in the ppt or slide?

Comment: Hi @SteveRindsberg Steve Rindsberg can you please assist where I enter this vba code in ppt

Comment: There are a couple of VBA/PowerPoint tutorials in the FAQ I maintain; start here: https://www.pptfaq.com/index.html#name_PROGRAMMING_POWERPOINT